# How to detect right-click event for Mac OS

Tags: java, macos

For windows and linux I am able to detect right click. But for mac I donot know how to detect right-click.

How to write java program to detect right click for Mac OS

Thanks
Sunil KUmar Sahoo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same as detecting a right-click on Windows or Linux—you call your given MouseEvent's `getButton()` method to check if `BUTTON3` was clicked. For example, take a look at the following snippet of an example MouseListener:

```
public class MyListener implements MouseListener
{
    // ... code ...

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.BUTTON3)
        {
            // Right-click happened
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only detects right-clicks if the user actually has a two-button mouse. Since most Mac mice had only one button as of not-too-long-ago, you might want to consider detecting Control-clicks as well (which was the common idiom for right-clicking back then). If you decide to do so, the implementation is pretty trivial: just add another check for if `event.isControlDown()` returns true.

Comment: FYI To generate a true Right-Click on a Mac, two finger click on the trackpad.

Comment: I think you meant MouseEvent.BUTTON3 -- MouseButton is something else.    (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseButton.html)

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using MouseEvent.BUTTON3, a bettter self docummenting approach is to use

```
if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(event))
   // do something
```

Also, if you are using this code to display a popup menu, then you should not be using this approach since each OS has different key strokes to inovoke the popup menu. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup).

Answer (score 3):

**Control-click support** needs to be added as Mac users might not be using a mouse with second button - e.g. A trackpad doesn't have a right mouse button.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   // Mac often uses control-click - isControlDown()
   if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) || e.isControlDown()) {
      // do something
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
private static boolean isRightClick(MouseEvent e) {
    return (e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3 ||
            (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac OS X") &&
                    (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0 &&
                    (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0));
}
```

`SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton()` will not work. It is incorrectly implemented for the Mac ctrl-click example because it checks whether `e.getModifiers() & 0x4` is non-zero. But the flag used for "command" is also `0x4`.

So it will report cmd-click as a right-click but won't report ctrl-click as one. Worse yet, cmd-click will also return `true` to `SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton()`. If your code is written to handle left-clicks one way and right-clicks another, and you use a second `if` rather than an `else if`, you're in for a nasty surprise when both execute.

For those who are interested, these are the complete `getModifiers()` and `getModifiersEx()` values for single-modifier clicks.

```
Left click: (button 1)
Basic: 0000010000 0000000000    16 0
Shift: 0000010001 0001000000    17 64
Ctrl:  0000010010 0010000000    18 128
Cmd:   0000010100 0100000000    20 256
Opt:   0000011000 1000000000    24 512

Mid click: (button 2)
Basic: 0000001000 1000000000    8 512
Shift: 0000001001 0001000000    9 64
Ctrl:  0000001010 0010000000    10 128
Cmd:   0000001100 0100000000    12 256
Opt:   0000001000 1000000000    8 512

Right click: (button 3)
Basic: 0000000100 0100000000    4 256
Shift: 0000000101 0001000000    5 64
Ctrl:  0000000110 0010000000    6 128
Cmd:   0000010100 0100000000    20 256
Opt:   0000001100 1000000000    12 512
```