# Java Mouse Event Right Click

Tags: java, swing, mouse, right-click, swingutilities

On my three button mouse `MouseEvent.BUTTON2`= Middle Click and `MouseEvent.BUTTON3` = Right Click.

Is this the case on a two button mouse?

Thanks

Answer (score 187, accepted):

To avoid any ambiguity, use the utilities methods from [SwingUtilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isLeftMouseButton(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) :

`SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent)`
`SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent)`
`SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(MouseEvent anEvent)`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, take a look at this thread which talks about the differences between platforms.

[How to detect right-click event for Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972512/how-to-detect-right-click-event-for-mac-os)

`BUTTON3` is the same across all platforms, being equal to the right mouse button. BUTTON2 is simply ignored if the middle button does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen

```
anEvent.isPopupTrigger()
```

be used before. I'm fairly new to Java so I'm happy to hear thoughts about this approach :)

Comment: yes, but according to http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4119064 and my own practice this function won't work correctly in Windows. And the bug lasts for 16 years already...