# Test context menu of Grid

Tags: java, swtbot, nebula

I have a org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.grid.Grid. To its header I've added a context menu (which is triggered by right click).

I have to create some tests for this grid, using SWTBot (which doesn't support grids).

**How can I open the context menu?**

I was able to get the GridHeader and even click it using

```
gridItem.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
```

To open the context menu I tried `SWT.BUTTON3` without success. I also tried some stuff suggested here: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386771/java-right-click-event), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386771/java-right-click-event) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972512/how-to-detect-right-click-event-for-mac-os) (there is no `contextMenu();` method).