# Yugioh GUI right click and left click

Tags: java, user-interface

I am making the GUI of yugioh game ana I want to summon monster with left click and set monster with right click how could I make that in a simple way ?

Comment: What technology are you using to make your UI?  Is it browser based?  Javascript?  Swing?  There are a lot of choices, and this will hugely impact how best to handle user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swing, this is probably what you'll need:  [Mouse Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
Once you've got your Swing elements on the page, take the one you want to respond to mouse events (I imagine that's play area?), and write a MouseAdapter class which handles the input to call your game logic for "set monster" and "summon monster".
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525733/java-mouse-event-right-click) then explains how to distinguish left- and right-clicks.

Please be aware though, there's a huge amount of work you'll need to do before you should be worrying about handling user input.  Prototyping is sensible, but it's a very good idea to design your data model and game logic before you start writing the UI.

Comment: I have finished from the game logic and I have to submit the last milestone which is about the UI today before 23:00 so could you give me a sample of the code please and thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed your deadline.  The first link I posted references this sample code: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MouseEventDemoProject/src/events/BlankArea.java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MouseEventDemoProject/src/events/MouseEventDemo.java - these should give you everything you need.