# How do I detect a mouse click in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, mouse

So I started playing around with setting up key for different functions in my application and I was wondering is there a way to set the right/left mouse click to do something? I was not able to find any mouse events in the KeyCode.java 
And I am not sure how to application that.

Here is my code:

```
public class Exercise_31 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        PendulumPane pendulumPane = new PendulumPane(500, 500);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pendulumPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pendulum Animation");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        pendulumPane.play();
        primaryStage.show();


        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e-> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case UP: pendulumPane.increase(); break;
                case DOWN: pendulumPane.decrease(); break;
                case LEFTMOUSECLICK?  
            }
        });


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    private class PendulumPane extends Pane {

        private double w = 400;
        private double h;
        PathTransition bPath;

        Circle topC;
        Circle lowerC;
        Line line;
        Arc arc;

        PendulumPane(double width, double height) {

            w = width;
            h = height;
            setPrefWidth(w);
            setPrefHeight(h);
            arc = new Arc(w / 2, h * 0.8, w * 0.15, w * 0.15, 180, 180);
            arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            lowerC = new Circle(arc.getCenterX() - arc.getRadiusX(), arc.getCenterY(), 10);
            topC = new Circle(arc.getCenterX(), arc.getCenterY() - h / 2, lowerC.getRadius() / 2);
            arc = new Arc(topC.getCenterX(), topC.getCenterY(), w / 2, h / 2, 240, 60);
            line = new Line(
                    topC.getCenterX(), topC.getCenterY(),
                    lowerC.getCenterX(), lowerC.getCenterY());

            line.endXProperty().bind(lowerC.translateXProperty().add(lowerC.getCenterX()));
            line.endYProperty().bind(lowerC.translateYProperty().add(lowerC.getCenterY()));
            bPath = new PathTransition();
            bPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
            bPath.setPath(arc);
            bPath.setNode(lowerC);
            bPath.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.NONE);
            bPath.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
            bPath.setAutoReverse(true);

            getChildren().addAll(lowerC, topC,line);

        }

        public void play() {
            bPath.play();
        }


        public void increase() {
            bPath.setRate(bPath.getCurrentRate() + 1);
        }

        public void decrease() {
            bPath.setRate(bPath.getCurrentRate() - 1);
        }

        public void stop() {
            bPath.setRate(bPath.getCurrentRate() * 0);
        }

        public void start() {
            bPath.setRate(bPath.getCurrentRate() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to make right clicking your mouse button stop the movement and left clicking start it again. How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: The mouse isn't keyboard input. You need to use the `setOnMousePressed` (or similar) method to capture mouse clicks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Mouse Event Right Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525733/java-mouse-event-right-click)

Comment: @Blip that question and its answers are all about Swing though, not JavaFX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event is a `KeyEvent`. If you define a listener on for the mouse (e.g. `setOnMouseReleased` you get a `MouseEvent` and on that one you have functions to check if certain keys are pressed that are usually combined with a mouse click:

```
event.isAltDown();
event.isControlDown();
event.isMetaDown();
```

If you need something more you will have to implement it yourself.
See the JavaDoc for [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).