# How would I go about including Ctrl+Click as a right-click? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, right-click, keylistener, mouselistener

I have an option to right-click. But users that need to use `Ctrl + Click` cannot use right-click because Java only allows for the right-click button to be hit.

Does anyone know how I can allow for `Ctrl + Click`, as well as the right-click button?

Thanks!

Comment: I currently use something like InputButton == InputEvent 3 or something. IDK I can't remember, hold on a sec.

Comment: I currently use `InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK` to determine a right click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to support users on Macs with one button mice. Here's another question that addressed this issue: [How to detect right-click event for Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972512/how-to-detect-right-click-event-for-mac-os)

Check out the answer that wasn't accepted as that appears to be the best solution. Long story short, you want to use `SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(event)`.